# get page description from page url without slowdowing the page load

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to get page description from page url without slowdowing the page load? via java script or php or any language?

For example I would send this input:

```
http://www.facebook.com
```

and get this output:

```
Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, ...
```

How I can do it?

Comment: yes but websites like facebook.com are timedout ! btw thanks for the code bro it really works fine with other sites !

Comment: are you behind a proxy by any chance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function `file_get_contents($url)` . For more help, refer to [this](http://www.tildemark.com/getting-website-title-and-description/)

[1](http://www.tildemark.com/getting-website-title-and-description/): http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php . You may need to do `urlencode` if the URL contains some spaces . As for the parsing part, I have found some code on the web . [Here](http://www.tildemark.com/getting-website-title-and-description/) is the link. Do let know

Code :

```
 <?php
function getMetaTitle($content){
//echo "AAAAA".$content;
$pattern = "|<[\s]*title[\s]*>([^<]+)<[\s]*/[\s]*title[\s]*>|Ui";
if(preg_match($pattern, $content, $match))
{
    //echo $match[1];
    return $match[1];
}
else
    return false;
}   
    //echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
$url = "your url here";

$str = file_get_contents($url);

$title1 = getMetaTitle($str);
echo $title1;
//echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the similar feature to create a somewhat Facebook like feature and fetch title, description and image.
I used [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for it, so even you can try DOMDocument to parse the page. Its very useful to parse the HTML page as per the HTML tags or attributes.

With the combination of ajax (by keeping your PHP script on your domain) you can pass the url to the PHP script (similar to below) which in turn will get back the required details from the website.

Sample code:

```
$url = ''; // this will be your URL
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// added @ to suppress the errors
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('title') as $title)
{
   $arrDetails['title'] = $title->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: thnks for helping and hope you know about DOM, i have a new problem with DOM can you help me with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464412/how-to-just-get-urls-inside-a-image-anchor-tag-using-dom

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents($url) then parse the  tag, OR any description.
Then save the couple url - description to a local cache to avoid requesting continuously the page.