# Get source of a web page via file_get_html

Tags: php

I use file_get_html to simple html DOM but i cant figure out how to get page source of a url!
Is there any way? im not talking about paintext !

Thanks

Comment: im sry,they are not working for me,i tried whole day to fetch details from another page...err im soo tired f this..

Comment: did you solve your prev question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459649/get-page-discription-from-page-url-without-slowdowing-the-page-load/10459822#10459822

Comment: no becz im new to here as well as to php !

Comment: I have added the code , which worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `file_get_contents`. It will fetch the source of a website url

if you want to see the source code try this

```
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You can do this using CURL also

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: it do not fetch the source intead it is loading this page url inside current page !!!!!

Comment: @DilonPerera: It is fetching the source, thats why you are seeing the page inside the current page.

Comment: It is not for me this link it says forbidden 403 http://www.london2012.com/photos/galleryid=1393639/index.html#giant-olympic-rings-unveiled-tower-bridge-1257803