# How to just get urls inside a image anchor tag using SimpleHTMLDOM

Tags: php

I use SimpleHTMLDOM to grab stuff from other web page but i have a problem how to just get urls inside of image ancor tag because that web page consists linking anchor tags as well as image anchor tags ! but i just want to get href value in side the image anchor tag !

```
<a href="I DO NOT NEED THIS VALUE"><a/>


<a href="I NEED THIS VALUE"><img src="xxxx"><a/>
```

but when call for the DOM its returns all the href URLs including linking anchor URLs ! I just need the URLs inside image anchor tag !

i use this code to call..

```
$hrefl = $html->find('a');

$count = 1;

for( $i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){

              echo $hrefl[$count]->href;
              $count++;

 }
```

Comment: have you tried the $html->find('a img') selector? With this, you should receive only anchor tags wraped around an image tag.

Comment: yes ! but then i can onlt get src="xx" values not href values ! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the href attribute of every link that contains an image tag. With xpath it's quite simple:

```
//a/img/../@href
```

You wrote that you use DOM, your code looks like written with simple html dom. That library is limited and nowadays not needed any longer because PHP has the `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` objects. I think simple html DOM has no xpath,

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$hrefs = $xpath->query('//a/img/../@href');
$count = $hrefs->length;
foreach($hrefs as $href)
{
    echo $href->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/WpADYFWI)

Comment: there are many image tags on that page..is it possible to display them all using DOMDocument? i think we can just get one result ! i really dont knw abt DOMdocument.. help me!

Comment: Sure, I edited the answe, it also had some errors because of typing quickly. Documentation about DOMDocument is here: http://php.net/DOMDocument

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are using [simplehtmldom library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for the parsing purpose
I am not very much aware of it, I use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for all my parsing purpose.

Very quick solution which I can suggest, is check whether the anchor tag has the image inside it, if yes get the value, otherwise skip it.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($urlofhtmlpage);

    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
        foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
            echo $a->getAttribute('href');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I found this code was more suited as you had control over both the href and img tag. thanks @swapnilsarwe

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$hrefl = $html->find('a');

$count = 1;

for( $i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
  $img = $hrefl[$count]->find('img');
  // check if var exists and is valid               
  if ($img ... ) { 
    echo $hrefl[$count]->href;
  }
  $count++;
 }
```